# How RedirectToAction which returna partial view can return a full view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am doing a redirect to an action which in turn displays the content within a `PartialView`

```
return PartialView(data);
```

I do the Redirect as such:

```
return RedirectToAction("SpkAction",  new { id = ID});
```

The redirect works fine and I do get to the `SpkAction` corrrectly.
But when the PartialView is rendered it ONLY shows the `PartialView` and not the whole form.

How do I get the `PartialView` to show the whole form and not just the `PartialView` using a `RedirectToAction` that goes to an action that which returns a `PartialView`?

Comment: I removed the jQuery tag as I don't see how it's related to your question. Am I right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I get the PartialView to show the whole form and not just the PartialView using a RedirectToAction that goes to an action that which returns a PartialView?

**You can't.**

If you redirect to an action returning a `PartialView` how in the name of  do you expect it to return a full view?

Redirect to an action returning a `View`.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is render the action in the view, and not redirect to it from the controller. Place this where you would want the partial to be in your view :

```
@Html.Action("SpkAction", new { id = ID})
```

If you are using Razor view engine that is.

Otherwise redirecting to an action that only renders a partial is gonna result in just that partial being visible in the browser.

Comment: `@Html.Action` will add the view when it was called, you can do what you're trying to do, or at least what it looks like you want to do.

Comment: From what I understand he is trying to include a child action within another action, but I could be wrong.